# Issues using Choropleth

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, choropleth

Currently trying to learn cloropleth - fairly a noob with this.

Problem:
I'm currently using a Michigan Counties GeoJSON file and am trying to draw a map of the state showcasing the percentage of people that opted for John. In return though, I only get an empty colorless map of the US with a legend on the side. Like so:[image]

Full dataset:
https://pastebin.com/x52E0Wii

**My GeoJSON file can be found here**: https://gis-michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/67a8ff23b5f54f15b7133b8c30981441/explore?location=44.847247%2C-86.594000%2C7.73

**The code I'm using:**

```
fig = px.choropleth(statistical_data, 
                    locations = 'NAME', 
                    locationmode = 'ISO-3', 
                    geojson = michigan_counties, 
                    color = '%John',
                   featureidkey = 'properties.NAME')
fig.show()
```

I was expecting a focused map of Michigan counties color coded with percentage of people who opted for John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The association between user data and geojosn is incorrect. In your data example, Maker, not fips, is the county name, so associate the name with the geojson property. Also, you do not need to set the location mode in this case. Since you presented 3 user data, the attached image shows only 3 regions. Also the geojosn data, but I could not get it correctly, so I used geosjon in the reference. Please make sure that the geojson property used has a name field.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(statistical_data, 
                    locations = 'NAME', 
                    geojson = counties, 
                    color = '%John',
                   featureidkey = 'properties.NAME',
                   scope='usa')

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wait, why is "Mark" the input for locations? Why wouldn't it be "NAME"? I thought the locations argument had to be a column in the statistical_data set that is also present in the properties under features.

Comment: Sorry, the columns were off in your data capture, NAME is correct.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for clarifying. Additionally, I used your json file, and was able to get something on a map, but it doesn't come together as the state of Michigan. Why are all the counties so scattered? I was thinking they would come together nicely forming the shape of the state. I can send you the full version of my dataset. I've linked it in the original problem - appreciate your help!

Comment: Oh, I know why. The geojson file shared seems to be for the entirety of the US. There could be duplicate county names. Ostego is a county in New York and Michigan.

Comment: I had the same situation while creating the graph, so I changed only the data you presented. I see that was the reason.